false negative as a conditional probability
Suppose we have a test for covid with a false negative rate of 4%. Let $T$ be a positive test result for Covid and $C$ for a person having Covid.
Does that mean $P(C| \neg T)=0.04$, or $P(\neg T| C)=0.04$ or $P(T \mid \neg C)=0.04$?
The lecture below seems to say $P(T \mid \neg C)=0.04$...is that right or wrong?
According to Wikipedia, "the false negative rate (FNR) is the proportion of positives which yield negative test outcomes with the test, i.e., the conditional probability of a negative test result given that the condition being looked for is present."
So this would be $P(\neg T | C)=0.04$. If that is the case, then wouldn't $P(T |C)=0.96$,


It appears the term "false negative rate" is misused here. Then I see "ML" in the course title and I'm not surprised.

Wikipedia has used confusing wording. By "the proportion of positives" they actually mean the proportion of diseased,
and FNR = proportion of diseased giving a negative result,
The following table should make it clear, with $D,D^c$ representing diseased, not diseased, and $+,-$ representing tested positive, negative
$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}\hline 
 &  + &  -  \\ \hline 
D & TP & FN \\ \hline
D^c & FP & TN \\ \hline \end{array}$
You can have a look here which also talks about sensitivity , specificity.
I hope this clears up whatever confusion you are having
$\textbf{Added}$
The material has messed up.
Using their symbols, it has given a true negative rate of $96\%$
The formula is ok upto $\dfrac{P(T|C)P(C)}{P(T|C)P(C)+(1-P(\lnot T|\lnot C))(1-P(C))}$
but it should directly translate to
$\dfrac{0.938\cdot 0.01}{(0.938\cdot0.01 + 0.04\cdot0.99)}, \approx 0.19$
instead of first trying to simplify the formula before putting in the value of P(C), which makes it an unfamiliar one.
Anyway, they got the answer right after all the confusion !

$\textbf{Added Eplanation}$
False negative rate doesn't enter the computation at all
As already mentioned, $(P(\lnot T|\lnot C)$ is the true negative rate, and the $0,04$ used in the computation is $1 -TNR =$ false positive rate
False negative rate is not used in the computation, but if you must know, it is  $P(\lnot T\mid C) = 1 - TPR$
Really, so many terms are unnecessarily used to create confusion, rewriting the the quadrant method for absolute clarity,
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}\hline 
Incidence & Tests\; Positive & Tests\; Negative  \\ \hline 
C: 0.01 & TPR=0.938 & FNR =0.062 \\ \hline
\lnot C: 0.99 & FPR=0.04 & TNR =0.96 \\ \hline \end{array}

Yes, I agree that the wording in Wikipedia is confusing, and thank you for introducing me to your nice notation involving +/- and D and D^c. But your answer does not state which conditional probability FNR refers to, and if the example worked out in the photo is wrong, which is my question. I think it is P(-| D)=0.04

@usr0192: Sorry, I was away, I'll add material to resolve the confusion presently.

@usr0192: If the answer has resolved your confusion, you could tick it to close the case.

I'm still confused about this: Let  be a positive test result for Covid and
for a person having Covid.
Does a "false negative rate" of 4%  mean (|¬)=0.04
, or (¬|)=0.04 or (∣¬)=0.04

The false negative rate is not 0.04, in fact it won't come into the computations needed. Still, if you want to know just for information, $FNR = P(\lnot T\mid C) = 1 - TPR;$ I have explained at greater length in added material
